# toggle image by changing image src

Tags: javascript

I wish to toggle between images by clicking on a button, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there anything wrong with the code below?

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById("mySVGCanvas")); 

var image1 = paper.image("https://tromoticons.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/y-u-no.png?w=350&h=300&crop=1", 10, 10, 100, 100);

var myState = 0

button1.node.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log("this part is working...");
        if (myState === 0){
            myState = 1;
            image1.src = "http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/trollface/success-troll-smiley-emoticon.png"

        } else{
            myState = 0;
            image1.src = "https://tromoticons.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/y-u-no.png?w=350&h=300&crop=1"

            };
        }
```

Comment: Use class instead and use `background-image` and toggle class

Comment: don't set myState = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

Even if the Raphael method `image()` does create an [SVGImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image), inside a Raphael Object and that there is no src attribute on this element, meaning you should use `image1.node.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", 'href', yourSrc)`, the Raphael method `attr('src', 'yourSrc')` does take care of it :

```js
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 200);

var image1 = paper.image("https://tromoticons.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/y-u-no.png?w=350&h=300&crop=1", 10, 10, 100, 100);

var myState = 0;
var button1 = paper.circle(10, 10, 20);
button1.attr("fill", "#f00");
button1.node.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (myState === 0) {
    myState = 1;
    image1.attr('src', "http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/trollface/success-troll-smiley-emoticon.png");
  } else {
    myState = 0;
    image1.attr('src', "https://tromoticons.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/y-u-no.png?w=350&h=300&crop=1");
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/1.5.2/raphael-min.js"></script>
```